# Issue when trying to inner join on two unique identifiers

Tags: string, type-conversion, inner-join, uniqueidentifier

I am looking to join two tables together that have the same values. The data from table 1 has been uploaded via Microsoft excel, while the data from table 2 is stored on our internal server.

Here is my query:

```
    select * from [table1] 
    inner join [table2].[ID] 
    on [table1].[ID] = [table2].[ID];
```

When i go to execute, this message pops up:

> "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."

Here are the examples of what each Id looks like in each table.

- Table 1- CD9430AB-8FC6-4AA2-9C15-425D74258FA2
- Table 2- 6C95E5A0-6621-4D85-A91C-794B57738FBB

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It sounds like the data uploaded from excel is being saved as a string instead of an ID. Look at how that is imported, and if you can control the record structure

Comment: You can use `select distinct SQL_Variant_Property( Id, 'BaseType' ) from Table1;` and `select distinct SQL_Variant_Property( Id, 'BaseType' ) from Table2;` to see the data types of the two columns. Then refer to [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [Implicit Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-conversions).

Answer (score 0):

One of your values in your column I probably contains some illegal chars for a GUID, such as spaces or characters in the range G to Z

As such you'll probably have more success doing the conversion based on string equality:

```
select * from [table1] 
inner join [table2].[ID] 
on cast([table1].[ID] as varchar) = cast([table2].[ID] as varchar)
```

I'd consider fixing up your broken data and converting the column to GUIDs rather than storing strings though